# Create listbox as Open File Dialog control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to create custom file dialog box with several validations. So I've chosen list box with multiple columns. I want to show all files of a specific location in this list box with horizontal scroll bar. I am facing a problem. I want to set the column width property to *Auto* so that if a file has longer name the column width automatically increased accordingly. I didn't find any "Auto Width" property, so I have to manually put the width of the column. I am stuck by this problem.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you don't define a width to your column, it must set automatically at the size of it's content. Obviously, the total width of all your columns can't be greater than its container.

Comment: @Zaphod I have to give some value in ColumnWidth property of ListBox control. It is not accepting blank value and if i am giving 0 value so still it is croping name of files.

Comment: Can you call the AutoResizeColumn method on the ListView? It has a ResizeStyle parameter that mentions resizing it based on the size of the column's content http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwd33cyk.aspx

Comment: You can measure a size needed to draw the file name using `graphics` object from the `listbox` that draws the string. And every time you read a file name, you save the largest size into a variable. Then, at the end, you can re-size your column to that size.

Answer (score 0):

Take this pseudo-code and use listbox graphics to measure string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

```
int colWidth, nextWidth;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    nextWidth = MeasureFileName(file);
    if (colWidth < nextWidth) colWidth= nextWidth;

    // Add file to list
}  

// set column width here to value in "colWidth"
```